# Swift makefile with swiftc

Tags: swift, makefile

I am trying to create a simple makefile to compile swift code.
Here is my Makefile:

```
NAME        = computor

DIRS        = ComputorV1/

LIST        =   Parser.swift    \
            main.swift

SOURCE      = $(addprefix $(DIRS), $(LIST))
OBJ     = $(patsubst %.swift,%.o,$(SOURCE))

all:
    @make $(NAME)

%.o: %.swift
    @swiftc -c $< -o $@

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    @swiftc $(OBJ) -o $(NAME)

clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJ)

fclean: clean
    @rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

.PHONY: all clean fclean re debug test
```

But when I am trying to make it, I always get an error

> "ComputorV1/main.swift:10:14: error: cannot find 'Parser' in scope
> let parser = Parser()"

main.swift and Parser.swift code are simply

```
import Foundation

let parser = Parser()
```

and

```
final class Parser {

    init() {
        print("privet")
    }
}
```

Where I did wrong? Maybe there is a some flag option for swiftc to ling one *.swift file with another, but I can't find that

Comment: Looks like `Makefile` is not relevant to the question.
It would be shorter if you just provide two Swift files, and command line used to compile it. And it would attract answers from people that only know Swift.

Comment: @MichalGajda, the thing is I definitely need to use makefile to build program

Comment: @EricAya, tried open and public - nothing helps :(

Comment: Disclaimer: I know *nothing* about makefiles. But here's what I see: Parser.swift is not linked to main.swift. Without any make script I would do `swiftc Parser.swift main.swift` to compile the program, so maybe try to reproduce this command using your makefile.

Comment: And contrary to what I said in a previous comment, `swiftc Parser.swift main.swift` works without needing to declare Parser class as public.

Comment: Yes, it will work in that way, but if you want to have a good makefile, you need to compile object (.o) files first. So, if I try to do that with "swiftc -c main.swift", I'll got an error

Comment: @TheWeaklessOne StackOverflow is an excellent place to post a narrow, well-defined question in a single domain.

By requiring answerer to know both Makefile, and Swift you make it harder to get the answer.

Please note that the first answer actually explains how to break this problem into smaller one that does not involve Makefile. That is how best engineers solve problems: by making them smaller.

Answer (score 0):

`Makefile` generates a sequence of commands that you can show by using `make clean; make --dry-run`. This sequence of commands will be easily recognized by Swift specialists.

In order to debug the problem, you may compare output of `make --dry-run` with results of running these commands by hand. Or alter `Makefile` to get a similar result.